# Controls in panel are hidden until I resize the window

Tags: .net, winforms, label, panel, groupbox

I've been having issues with controls being "cut-off" from a panel. However when i manually start resizing the form, the missing controls start to re-appear after every resize.
I've created a test app to show this issue.
The app itself adds a panel on the main form.
Within this panel i add 10 groupboxes with each groupbox having 100 labels.
Below are the steps to create the test app and reproduce the issue (I've only tried this with .NET 4.6.1 and visual studio 2017 so far)

- Create a new windows forms project
- Update the constructor of the default form to be as below

  ```
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      // My stuff
      var panContents = new Panel();
      panContents.AutoScroll = true;
      panContents.AutoSize = true;
      panContents.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
      panContents.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      for (int g = 10; g >= 0; g--)
      {
          var groupBox = new GroupBox();
          groupBox.AutoSize = true;
          groupBox.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
          groupBox.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
          groupBox.Text = "Group " + g;

          var mainPanel = new Panel();
          mainPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
          mainPanel.AutoSize = true;
          mainPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
          for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
          {
              var con = new Label();
              con.Text = "Label " + i;
              con.Height = 100;
              con.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
              mainPanel.Controls.Add(con);
          }
          groupBox.Controls.Add(mainPanel);
          panContents.Controls.Add(groupBox);
      }

      this.Controls.Add(panContents);
  }
  ```
- Run the project (without resizing the form)
- Scroll to near the bottom of the form, you'll notice not all the 10 group boxes are rendered
- Manually resize the form, you'll notice some of the missing labels and groupboxes start to appear
- Keep resizing the form until all the controls are shown

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I thought maybe it was to do with the limit of the size of the panel. However if this was the case, i wouldn't expect resizing the form to start showing these missing controls.

PS I know i can get around this issue by using tabs or paging. However I want to know why I'm seeing the behaviour that I'm seeing (Ideally i want to avoid using tabs or paging)

Comment: You may have caused the Form/Panel to scroll beyond the maximum scroll value (IIRC `32,767`).

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought....however that doesn't explain why resizing the form causes more and more controls to appear. If I'd hit the panel limit, then resizing the form shouldn't have any impact on the amount of controls being shown...if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yas,

This was a rather intriguing problem--didn't quite grasp it until loading/running your code. I happen to agree with Jimi--that you're probably running up against an internal limitation, however bizarre that limitation appears to be. As you pointed out, tweaking the height/width of the form shouldn't overcome a limitation. So whatever's going on internally, it's a bit odd and unexpected.

But I have a solution for you: It's admittedly a kludge but sometimes that's our only option. If your project specs require a form like the one you presented--a form that ends up with a height value well over 100,000, then this solution should fit the bill.

Add the following code to the end of your Form1 initialization code, shown in your original post (see below). What I've done is programmatically "tweaked" the height of the form ever so slightly--repeatedly--until all of the panels have been fully rendered. I think this is going to be your best bet.

For the record, I had spent quite a bit of time on this. I had tried various combinations of Refresh() on various controls, DoEvents(), etc., to no avail. I even tried not using docking and autosizing, in favor of setting top and heights manually (that didn't work either). Thus, I think the code below is really the only way to fix this, aside from a fix from Microsoft.

** For the code below to work, add this line immediately after your code's InitializeComponent(); line:

```
this.Show();
```

Then add this code after your code's closing brace:

```
     // fix the panContents panel
     long currentMaximum = 0;
     while (true)
     {
        var preserveHeight = this.Height;
        // tweak the height
        this.Height += 1;
        // set it back the height
        this.Height = preserveHeight;

        // test to see if the scroll bar max remains at its previous value
        // if it does, we're done
        if (currentMaximum == panContents.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
           break;

        // otherwise, preserve the current maximum scroll bar position
        currentMaximum = panContents.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

        // now scroll to the bottom of the panel
        panContents.VerticalScroll.Value = panContents.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
        // necessary step to ensure scroll bar value is set
        panContents.PerformLayout();
     }

     // scroll to the top
     panContents.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
     // necessary step to ensure scroll bar value is set
     panContents.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: I love the hack you've done :)  I can see what you're attempting but it isn't working when I've added beneath my code (The while loop exits after the second iteration because panContents.VerticalScroll.Maximum seems to always be 100). I'll play around with the idea.....but i don't know if I'd want this in my code (hate hacks :P) I doubt Microsoft will do anything about it. I wonder if theres any other control that i can use as a replacement (ListView, Datagridview) or they might have height limits to......

Comment: Give me a few minutes--my system never has a value of 100--it is the full value of the form height. I will comment further soon...

Comment: I amended my answer... There may be a way to use the 100% maximum value, but I don't think that will work, as you discovered. I know it's a hack but, really, you've discovered what's clearly a bug. There is no reason why your code shouldn't work as written. I agree that Microsoft likely won't fix this, so I think the hack might be your only viable option if in fact this design is what you need.

Comment: While I think I've provided a satisfactory solution to your problem [please accept if you agree] (because the answer to your question is: You discovered a bug in Winforms!--but I think you wanted a solution too), you might want to try some of the components from DevExpress or Syncfusion. I suspect that maybe a third-party panel control that supports scrolling might work, as this appears to be a panel-control issue. If you discover a suitable alternative control, update us!

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've marked it as the answer because it certainly looks like an issue with winforms/microsoft. A "hack" is probably the only viable solution to the panel issue. My gut instinct feels that i probably need to redesign the layout so that i avoid getting anywhere near the panel limit ;(

Comment: Thanks and agreed. You could try placing each groupbox in its own row of a scrolling grid control rather than place all groupbox controls in a single panel, but that's just one possibility that might work. Meanwhile, I had never seen this behavior and shame on Microsoft for not honoring Refresh() requests on the panel/form control...